# Not able to apply my filters only for those 2 dropdowns why?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 3 dropdowns with differents options. 1 is working `taste` except for those 2: `comments` and `types`.when you select one or several options then my table is filtered. For example, if I choose option `Good` for dropdown `taste` then  my table rendering contains all the row with `taste` is `Good`.

In my `filters` function, I think it's because for `comments`, I have an integer that needs to be converted into string?? The second one, i don't know how to deal with. If I choose to filter by `small` it means display data where `small:1`, same logic for `tall` and `medium`.

Do you see what's wrong in my `filtres` function ??

```
export default function Display() {
  const { menuId } = useParams();
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);

  const [comments, setComments] = useState([
    { label: "1", value: "1", name: "1", selected: false },
    { label: "2", value: "2", name: "2", selected: false },
    { label: "3", value: "3", name: "3", selected: false }
  ]);

  const [types, setTypes] = useState([
    { label: "medium", value: "medium", name: "Medium", selected: false },
    { label: "tall", value: "tall", name: "Tall", selected: false },
    { label: "small", value: "small", name: "Small", selected: false }
  ]);

  const [tastes, setTastes] = useState([
    { label: "Bad", value: "Bad", name: "Bad", selected: false },
    { label: "Good", value: "Good", name: "Good", selected: false },
    { label: "Medium", value: "Medium", name: "Medium", selected: false }
  ]);


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post("", {menuId:parsInt(menuId)
      .then((res) => {
        const menus = res.data.menus;
        setMenus([
          ...menus.filter((i) => i.status === "Good"),
          ...menus.filter((i) => i.status !== "Good")
        ]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [menuId]);


  const matchDdata = menus.filter(({ id }) => {
    return !hidden[id];
});

  const filters = matchData.filter((menus) => {
    const allComments = comments.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionComments = comments
      .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
      .map(({ value }) => value);

    const allTypes = types.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionTypes = types
      .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
      .map(({ value }) => value.toString());

    const allTastes = tastes.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionTastes = tastes
      .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
      .map(({ value }) => value);

    const isSelComments = allComments || optionTastes.indexOf(menus.taste) >= 0;
    const isSelTypes = allTypes || optionTypes.indexOf(menus.taste) >= 0;
    const isSelTaste = allTastes || optionTastes.indexOf(menus.taste) >= 0;
  return (isSelComments && isSelTypes && isSelTaste);});

const reset = (list) =>
  list.map((e) => ({
    ...e,
    selected: false
}));

const cancel = () => {
    setComments(reset(comments));
    setTypes(reset(types));
    setTastes(reset(tastes))
};

  const data = [
    {
      Header: "id",
      accessor: (row) => row.id
    },
    ...  
  ];

   return (
    <div >      
        <div>
          <Button onClick={cancel}>cancel</Button>
        </div>

      <div>
        <Drop
          placeholder={"Types"}
          items={types}
          onSelect={dropSelection(setTypes)}
          hasAll
        />
        <Drop
          placeholder={"Types"}
          items={comments}
          onSelect={dropSelection(setComments)}
          hasAll
        />    
        <Drop
          placeholder={"Tastes"}
          items={tastes}
          onSelect={dropSelection(setTastes)}
          hasAll
        />    
  
      </div>     
      <Table     
          data={filters}
          columns={data}
          withCellBorder
          withRowBorder
          withSorting
          withPagination
          withColumnSelect
          rowProps={getRowProps}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my json from my api for `menuId:1`:

```
[
    {
      "id": "Menu1",

          "name": "Pea Soup",
          "description": "Creamy pea soup topped with melted cheese and sourdough croutons.",
          "types": 
            {
              "small": 0,
              "tall": 1,
              "medium":0
            }
          ,
          "taste": "Good",
          "comments": 3,
          "price": "Low",        
          "status": "Pending",
          "apply": 1
     },
       ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function for `types` should be

```
const isSelTypes = allTypes || optionTypes.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (menus.types[cur]) acc = true;
    return acc;
}, false);
```

So your `filters` will be

```
const filters = matchData.filter((menus) => {
    const allComments = comments.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionComments = comments
        .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
        .map(({ value }) => parseInt(value));

    const allTypes = types.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionTypes = types
        .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
        .map(({ value }) => value.toString());

    const allTastes = tastes.every((i) => i.selected === false);
    const optionTastes = tastes
        .filter((entity) => entity.selected)
        .map(({ value }) => value);

    const isSelComments =
        allComments || optionComments.indexOf(menus.comments) >= 0;
    const isSelTaste = allTastes || optionTastes.indexOf(menus.taste) >= 0;
    const isSelTypes = allTypes || optionTypes.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (menus.types[cur.toLowerCase()] == 1) acc = true;
        return acc;
    }, false);
    return isSelComments && isSelTypes && isSelTaste;
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-brahmagupta-2o3h6k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The filter for `types` is not working. Maybe what I want is not clear : In my dropdown I have these options : `small`, `tall`, `medium`, and if I click on one of those, it means display the values where `value` is `1`

Comment: can you provide codesandbox example, it could be great

Comment: I can try but I think it's not working maybe because of those lines `const [types, setTypes]={ label: "medium", value: "medium", name: "Medium", selected: false },...` and in the filters function `if (menus.types[0][cur.toLowerCase()] == 1) acc = true;` But what I get from api is  `..."types": [{"small": 0,tall": 1,"medium":0}],` so, should I put `const [types, setTypes]={ label: "medium", value: "1", name: "Medium", selected: false },...` ??

Comment: Im not sure, i have created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-villani-njt200?file=/src/index.js) and it looks good

Comment: I've this error message in my console : `react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` when I click on `small` for example

Comment: @Zokulko can you give me your menu data? so i can test with my code

Comment: Yes  [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-sun-gxgz5j?file=/menus.json), I've just realize that  it's `[...types:{...}..]` and not `[...types:[{...}]..].` Sorry, I've update the code in my issue

Comment: oh, so that is the problem. I've updated my answer, you can check again [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-brahmagupta-2o3h6k?file=/src/App.js)